# How do I ensure ruby gems are installed in right place to be executed by bundler?

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

I seem to be constantly having problems with getting the gems in the right place (and not needing to use `sudo` when installing them.)

To address the `sudo` issue, I installed `rbenv` and then use that to install ruby 2.1.0 so that I had a separate one from Mac OSX system.

Then I installed bundler.  But when I install gems from a Gemfile with bundler, I cannot find them.

Between all the steps I have taken, such as adding lines to my .bash_profile and so forth, I have the following, but really just want a clear, straightforward way to manage gems and their local execution:

`gem env` :

**Edit: I removed everything and reset PATH -- still didn't fix anything, but you can see that gems are installed in one directory but when I call the executable, the command cannot be found:**

```
 RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 451) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/fongster/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

Here is what happens when I want to run, say `shotgun`:

`bash-3.2$ shotgun
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in`to_specs': Could not find 'shotgun' (>= 0) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Can someone point me to simple, straightforward directdions for ruby gem management on OSX so that:

- I don't need to use `sudo` to install gems
- I can use bundler to install from a Gemfile for a given project
- Those gems and their executables (shotgun, restclient, sass) can just be executed
- My local environment based on this set up 'just works' in heroku?
- I don't need to type `bundle exec` when I need to do stuff

Also some clarity on whether I need to always go to a bash shell (currently, I have been using `exec bash` to get my shell working).

EDIT:  Following the steps below and have this response upon bundle:

```
Errno::EEXIST: File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/fongster/.rbenv/shims/gem
An error occurred while installing backports (3.6.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install backports -v '3.6.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### From a clean start

You do not have to do anything apart from the plain steps [stated on the Bundler home page](http://bundler.io/):

- Do NOT use `sudo bundle ...`
- Do NOT change anything to your PATH
- Do not touch any `~/.file`
- Copy `require 'bundler/setup'` at the top of your first application file
- DO use bundle exec in front of all your Bundler-managed *"binaries"*

Everything just works using the nice defaults for a **developer** workstation. When you want to go further like running multiples Rubies side by side or deploying to prod or are fed up with typing `bundle exec` (which you should alias to `bex` using `alias bex='bundle exec'`) you can then [Read The Full Manual](http://bundler.io/), type `bundle install --binstubs` and install one of the Rubymongers (RBEnv, RVM).

### In your specific situation

I would restart from scratch:

- uninstall RBEnv (`rm -rf ~/.rbenv` and delete rbenv mentions in `grep rbenv ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.zshrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/*`)
- uninstall Bundler

Comment: As with any tool, do not install RBEnv until you need to put it to use ! Bundler is instantly useful as soon as you go beyond the Stdlib.

Comment: thanks....since this left me operate with fewer tools, I went with your approach for now and selected it as the right answer, thank you.

Comment: I get an error: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`

Comment: There is something about writing gems which always seems to want to my Library directory, but I don't want to write there because I need sudo.

Comment: @Angela We can not discuss this new issue here. Create a new question to present your problem.

Comment: what is the 'first application file'?

Comment: @DavidLeBauer The first file loaded when the application starts. You want Bundler to be ready as soon as possible. Please note that I think that this is no longer required under Ruby 2.x

Answer (score 8):

Use [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset). It works great and meets all your requirements. I have been using it for 2 years and have not had any problems. No issues with Heroku.

Here's my process for setting up a new Ruby project:

```
1. Create directory (or Rails app in new directory)
2. cd directory
3. Set ruby version: Use 2.1.0 or another version 
   rbenv local 2.1.0
4. Set gemset: replace app-name with the name of the app
   echo app-name > .rbenv-gemsets
5. Check gemset. Should be app-name global:
   rbenv gemset active
6. rbenv rehash
7. Create Gemfile
8. gem install bundler
9. bundle
```

When it does not work as expected, do `rbenv rehash`.

You should never need to install gems using `sudo`.

Regarding your shell, that could be causing problems. If a regular terminal doesn't work then there is probably another issue.

Since the issue seems related to your shell and PATH, here's my .bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

You may want to try replacing your .bash_profile with the above, or create a new user and see if the issue disappears.

Comment: alright, thanks -- right now my $PATH is filled with all kinds of things as I was tring to get it to work.  How do I reset and what should I set it to?  I've been manually assiging the config paths for Bundler and rubygems and don't want to do that.....

Comment: Do you still do the following from `rbenv`:==> Caveats
To use Homebrew's directories rather than ~/.rbenv add to your profile:
  export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv

To enable shims and autocompletion add to your profile:
  if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

Comment: Hi, I still get different install and execution paths:  I check by typing gem env:  bash-3.2$ restclient
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rest-client' (>= 0) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: I would clean out my path. See my updated answer. I don't think you need `export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv` or `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`

Comment: To "reset" your PATH, remove anything related to it in the . files in your home directory. Then close the terminal and open a new terminal. You probably need this one: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: Okay, I cleared ou path to default and then started up again....I get an error at `bundle` which I posted above.  going to go through the whole drill one more time after uninstalling and reinstalling `rbenv` to see if that changes anything....

Comment: I get the following:  I was thinking that it would all get installed into the gemset directory but it's in this particular directory: bash-3.2$ bundle show shotgun
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shotgun-0.9
bash-3.2$ gem which shotgun
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun.rb

Comment: Did you install `rbenv-gemset`? It looks like it could be a permissions issue. Did you install any gems with `sudo`? If so, I would uninstall them, do `rbenv rehash`, and then reinstall.

Comment: I did install it but didn't install with sudo