# Is there a version manager for Ruby gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm a new Rails developer. I recently took a class on Rails and now I'm trying to make sure I'm growing in my skill by self-assigning projects that push me. One thing I'm trying to do now is use Radiant CMS to build a blog site. However, I'm running into some problems downloading the Radiant gem. Here's what I did:

1. When I first tried `gem install radiant`, it installed most of the required gems but then threw a warning (which I unfortunately did not save verbatim), which was along the lines of:

   ```
   railties executable will overwrite rails executable. Overwrite? Y/n
   ```
2. Stupidly, I chose "Y". As soon as I did I tested my rails gem by writing `rails new testproject` and it failed. So I then re-ran `gem install rails`, told it to overwrite the "railties" executable, then ran `gem uninstall radiant` to get rid of the core radiant gem (although I do still have railties).
3. Now, my Rails gem is fixed, and I can create new Rails projects without an issue. However, I reinstalled the Radiant gem, and while it installed, it fails to create a project every time I run it.

I'm pretty sure I broke something, but I'm not terribly concerned about that. What I am concerned about is the fact that it seems that the Radiant gem doesn't really coexist well with the Rails gem, which leads me to my question:

**Is there any way to create separate, self-contained ruby gem environments where the current Ruby version will only use the gems in the specified environment?**

In essence, I'm looking for what rbenv does, but for collections of gems rather than Ruby versions.

Currently, I have Homebrew installed and I am using rbenv as my version manager. Everything I can find so far talks about managing gems on a project-by-project basis; I'm looking for something that will manage and keep separate the gems that create the projects in the first place. So, for example, `environment_a` contains `rails` and `httparty` while `environment_b` contains `radiant` and  `railties`.

I'm not above completely obliterating rbenv and all of my gems and starting from scratch, either, so that's a possibility (and an advantage of being a noob).

Comment: Both answers are correct, but your best solution is to read about RVM's use and support of [gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets), and what Bundler supplies, and then decide what works best for you. You can even use combinations of the two, such as RVM for simple default gemsets for the majority of your projects, especially simple ones, and Bundler for more complex or shared ones. One warning though, don't try to mix RVM and rbenv as they're both designed to handle managing Ruby versions and they'll conflict, driving you nuts so pick one or the other.

Comment: Hi everyone - thanks a lot for your responses! I downloaded rbenv-gemset and dug deeper into Bundler, and I found exactly what I was looking for. I also found [this](https://gist.github.com/MicahElliott/2407918), which helped me understand a little more of what I needed to do with Bundler.

I've been avoiding RVM, only because I'm using rbenv and because I want to understand what I'm doing a bit better before I use something more complicated than rbenv.

Thank you again for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset)

I think that it is better than RVM because it is less invasive.

I have been using rbenv and rbenv-gemset for about 2 years and find it easy to use. It makes it easy to encapsulate the Ruby and gemset in a project, run multiple Rubies and gemsets on one machine, and move a project to another machine.

You can use [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) to install other versions of Ruby. There is a trick to installing the latest versions of Ruby.

You may want to have a look at  [How do I ensure ruby gems are installed in right place to be executed by bundler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575245/how-do-i-ensure-ruby-gems-are-installed-in-right-place-to-be-executed-by-bundler) It has some relevant (and hopefully useful) info.

Answer (score 5):

You should check [bundler](http://bundler.io/), as it does exactly what you need.

Comment: And any recent version of Rails uses it by default

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

I think that it's called **RVM**.

Just like ***Chris Heald*** said, You can check more information about it @ [rvm.io/gemsets/basics](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics)

Comment: The OP is already using rbenv to manage their Ruby versions. RVM and rbenv will conflict, so that needs to be mentioned. The author of rbenv specifically says in [the documentation](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv): "Compatibility note: rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Please make sure to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell initialization files before installing rbenv."

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend bundler for versioning gems although both RVM and rbenv also have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You asked: **"Is there any way to create separate, self-contained ruby gem environments where the current Ruby version will only use the gems in the specified environment?"**

The best way to do it with **rvm** is entering your project's directory and then run:

```
rvm use ruby-x.y.z@your_project_name --ruby-version --create
```

where x.y.z is your Ruby version for that project, previously installed with **rvm install x.y.z**

For example, to use the newest Ruby version with a project named **acme** you would use

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```

and then

```
rvm use ruby-2.3.1@acme --ruby-version --create
```

This command would create two files in the projects directoty: **.ruby-version** and **.ruby-gemset**.

The file **.ruby-version** would contain just the version number. And the file **.ruby-gemset** would contain only the name off the gemset, the same name of your project (acme).

It happens that **rvm** is smart enough to check for these files and use the gemset specified, which will be located at **~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@acme** and your gems will be located at **~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@acme/gems**.

Some points:

1) Using your project's name as the gemset name is NOT mandatory. You may use anything you like. It's kind of a standard using project's name, but not mandatory.

2) rbenv probably has a way to do the same, but I don't use rbenv and really don't know how to do that.

Hope this answer helps.