# Bundle command not found mac

Tags: ruby, macos, bundler

I'm using ruby, and I was given a zip file with some ruby programs and it says:  inside the folder, run `bundle install` to install the packages required.

When I run the command in my terminal, it says `bundle command not found`.

Can someone please give me a detailed description of how I can fix this?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
gem install bundler
```

is how to do it.

You may want to use a tool such as [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage gems.

Comment: I get the following error when I try that:  You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory

Comment: Then use `sudo gem install bundler`.

Comment: I can swear I tried this earlier and it didn't work. But I just tried it again, and it worked. Haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TejaK, What worked?  `sudo ...`.  Don't use sudo for this.  Your system has ruby installed for things it does--and you don't want to touch the system install.  If you screw up the system install of ruby, you may screw up your whole operating system.  You need to install your own ruby to play with.  The best(and easiest) way to do that is with rvm(what I use) or rbenv.  Yes, you have to install rvm or rbenv first.  Once you get your own ruby installed, all you have to do is `gem install bundler`--no sudo.  To install rvm, see here:  https://rvm.io/rvm/install.

Comment: Why is rvm easier than rbenv?

Comment: Yeah all of the other threads also warned against using sudo, so I went ahead and used rbenv as B Seven suggested!

Comment: Here's a step by step process for setting up `rbenv` and `rbenv-gemset` for a project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575245/how-do-i-ensure-ruby-gems-are-installed-in-right-place-to-be-executed-by-bundler/26575400#26575400

Comment: Absolutely use sudo.

Comment: @RyanP - No, don't.

Answer (score 56):

Just reiterating that for those (at least on OSX) for whom

```
gem install bundler
```

Gives a permissions error, an option that seems to have worked for many people is to use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), which kind of adds a shim between your ruby commands (like `gem install`) and your environment (if my understanding is correct).

Definitely check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18554704/2223106).

The process is laid out fairly well under the above link. I chose to install via homebrew:

```
brew update
brew install rbenv
```

Then you have to add an argument command to your profile, which if you're using the common `~/.bash_profile`, can be done with:

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Which it looks like is adding a command to initialize rbenv via your shell.

Don't for get to start a new shell, possibly by opening a new terminal or using the `source ~/.bash_profile` command.

Make sure your `$PATH` has this `.rbenv/shims` BEFORE any other directory where your shell might be looking for Ruby (OSX comes with it's own version that we don't want to fiddle with): `echo $PATH`.

```
which ruby
/Users/mikekilmer/.rbenv/shims/ruby
#GOOD!
```

Now install a version of Ruby:

```
rbenv install 2.2.3
```

(See all possible versions with `rbenv install -l`).

Now we can use `rbenv global 2.2.3` to switch to a use the newer version of Ruby globally. (Hmm. I thought we *didn't* want to mess with the system version.) You could also try it with `rbenv local 2.2.3` or `rbenv shell 2.2.3`.

Finally run:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Now `ruby -v` should return `2.2.3` and `gem install bundler` should work.

Did here.

Comment: Saved me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Best answer! The key is detailed explanation for any kind of situations just executing the `gem install bundler` won't work. Thanks.

Comment: I learned more about Ruby in this answer than I learned in every other chance in the past!

Comment: Thanks @DouglasFischer. Much appreciate the compliment.

Comment: Very helpful post - thank you!! For people using .zsh, I added `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"` and `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"` to my `.zshrc` file before running `source ~/.zshrc` in my terminal to refresh

Answer (score 7):

Just run `gem install bundler` in your terminal.

There is a link to `bundler` you can take a look:[bundler](http://bundler.io/#getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Some ruby version managers like chruby and rbenv store gems separately for each version, so when you install a different version of ruby, you'll need to `gem install bundler`.

Answer (score 1):

Tried every solution here but didn't work out. Eventually I got this to work in two different methods:

- Set `alias bundle=/path/to/bundle` in `.bashrc` if you don't care the nastiness.
- Recreate a fresh dev env via `rbenv` and do `bundle install rails` will fix it (fixed my issue).

Answer (score -4):

Terminal -

```
sudo su
```

then your password:

change directory :

```
cd command .
```

if you do not have permissions to write to drive.

```
chmod 755 foldername.
```

And you can also mkdir command in terminal

```
mkdir /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0.1
```

copy and paste: `gem install bundler` paste to the terminal.

```
Fetching: bundler-1.16.2.gem (100%)
bundler's executable "bundle" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/bundle
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  y
bundler's executable "bundler" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/bundler
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  y
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 7 seconds
1 gem installed
```

works for OS X High Sierra.

Comment: 1. This is totally unreadable. You should indent commands with 4 spaces. 2. sudo is dangerous. As pointed out above, you are messing with the your systems ruby installation and might break your os. 3. There is lot of unnecessary stuff you do (see accepted answer)