# Rails can't find installed gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm following a tutorial for Rails that specifically asks for version `4.2.0` so I installed Rails with `sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.0` and it worked fine. When I try to create a new application with `rails _4.2.0 new test_app` I get an error message that says `/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb.315: in 'to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (=4.2.0) - did find: [railties-4.2.1] (Gem::LoadError)` and continues on for a little bit more.

I've tried installing that specific version of `railties` with `sudo gem install railties -v 4.2.0` but I still get the same error. Is it checking for/installing the gem in two different places?

EDIT: Running `gem list` yields the following output, clearly showing `railties (4.2.0)`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.0)
actionpack (4.2.1, 4.2.0)
actionview (4.2.1, 4.2.0)
activejob (4.2.1, 4.2.0)
activemodel (4.2.0)
activerecord (4.2.0)
activesupport (4.2.1, 4.2.0)
arel (6.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.9.9)
erubis (2.7.0)
globalid (0.3.5)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.2, 1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.2)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.6.1, 5.4.3)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rack (1.6.1)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.0)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
sprockets (3.1.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.1)
test-unit (3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use sudo for installing gems. Use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

Comment: I thought it'd be confusing to install so I avoided it for a while, but once I found [this tutorial for OS X,](https://mattbrictson.com/rails-osx-setup-guide) I went ahead and installed it and it runs great. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is good to keep things as simple as possible. It turns out that `rbenv` makes gem management simple. I suggest installing `rbenv gemset` as well: https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575245/how-do-i-ensure-ruby-gems-are-installed-in-right-place-to-be-executed-by-bundler/26575400#26575400 for step by step instructions.