# Installed gem can't load from rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am dabbling with ruby on rails for the first time and have run into an issue while trying to load a gem from a controller.

To install the gem, I added it to (the top just below `source`) the Gemfile and ran `bundle install`. The gem is shown as installed and is in the Gemfile.lock. When installing, I was prompted for sudo password and a `bundle show <gem>` shows it in a system path (`/var/lib/gems`).

In the controller (in `app/controllers/my_controller.rb`), I am requiring it as follows:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @somevar = dostuff
  end

  private

  def dostuff
     require 'some/lib'
     return "foo"
  end
end
```

When I access the app, I get the following error:

`cannot load such file -- some/lib`

If i put the `dostuff` function into `dostuff.rb` in the project root and execute it with `ruby dostuff.rb` the gem is loaded fine.

Am I missing something about how gems are loaded in a rails environment or am I loading it up incorrectly?

I have read through these similar questions but they have not resolved the problem:

[Rails can't find installed gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467272/rails-cant-find-installed-gem) - is `rbenv` the only solution? would like to try get this working with a system gem.
[Does Rails load all installed gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329006/does-rails-load-all-installed-gems) - im explicitly loading it but failing

Comment: Did you install it with sudo?

Comment: yep. bundle install prompted for paswd so assuming it was a sudo gem install. i actually just needed to restart 'rails server' process to find the gem

Comment: Better you use something like `rvm`. It's not recommended to install with sudo